# EC2 FTP User Directory change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chroot

Our EC2 instance setup has an ftp user that had successful setup through the `vsftpd` program with an original home directory of `\home\user\`, I followed the instructions on this [stack overflow](https://serverfault.com/questions/392601/how-to-add-user-with-sftp-ftp-access-to-var-www-html-website-abc-folder-on-a), and had the user's shell set to `/bin/false`

What I'm looking to do is make the ftp user login only accessible to a particular directory, a folder in the html directory - `\var\www\html\website.com\userfolder`

**What I've done:**

- Added `user` to a group `ftpgroup`
- Authorized access and ownership of the new directory to the user:ftponly
- Changed the user's home directory in `/etc/passwd`
- added `.ssh/authorized_keys` with user's key in the new directory
- changed ChrootDirectory in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to new directory
- changed the permissions on the directory to `chmod -R 775 user:ftpgroup`
- mounting `\var\www\html\website.com\userfolder`

Before these changes I was able to access the FTP, and now upon attempted access I receive the following errors from the Filezilla client:

> Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available
> (server sent:publickey) ... Status: Connection attempt failed with
> "ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out"

As it was working before, I'm thinking that it might have something to do with permissions, I'm just unsure of where else to change.
Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

After creating the user with vsftpd, the user now has access to the directory via FileZilla. 
I then added a link from the `home/{user}` directory to the `/var/www/html/{user}` directory.
The user can upload files to the home directory and can view it from the html directory.

This is a simple hack. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I tried using a symbolic link, but I was unable to access the files due to it being a chrooted user.

Comment: The admin/root owner on the server has to do the link. 
If you are the admin, you can do that with a `sudo`.

Comment: At this point I'm thinking that the issue might lie in some configuration as symbolic links don't generally work well with chrooted users. I've mounted the needed directory to the user's directory, there's just issues accessing the files via sftp on the new user after configuring the chrooted directory.